# Xamarin forms debugging tool for windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, forms, debugging, xamarin, web-inspector

Hello all i want to know if there is any debugger available to inspect the app in browser for web based app. example: we can inspect android apps in chrome.

Comment: Why would you want to inspect a Xamarin Forms app in a browser? It's a mobile app not a web app.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne Yes it is a mobile app but i can deploy it on windows desktop machine using windows 8.1 platform so kindly let me know is there any way to inspect the webviews of the same app.

Comment: It might be worth putting that information in your question. The details are a bit sparse at the moment.